# How can I style this span for a quote without causing this layout problem?

Tags: html, css

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUAxx/2/)

I am trying to format a quote so that it appears a certain way within a post.

Here is the CSS:

```
    .inner_quote {
        background:RGBA(255,250,205,.4);
        margin-left:50px;
        width:200px;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

The problem is that because I am doing `position:absolute;` there is no space allocated for the quote between the before text and the after text.

How can I get the quote to appear the way it currently does, but not have this layout problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Remove `position: absolute` and change the `<span>` tag to a `<div>` tag
2. Remove the `position: absolute` and add the property `display: block` within the `.inner_quote` css tag

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

set is as block element and position it relative.

```
.inner_quote {
            background:RGBA(255,250,205,.4);
            margin-left:50px;
            width:200px;
            position:relative;
            display: block;
        }
```

but you should also use `<blockquote>` to be semantic.